# Actionscript 3 Update DataGrid cell values dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, actionscript, cell, dataprovider

I have a `DataGrid maildg` which is being provided by `maildp:DataProvider`.

My program is dynamically looping through the Datagrid Provider, and changing one or more values in it.

However, when a value is changed, this doesn't appear on the actual datagrid. When clicking on the datagrid, it updates itself. I'd like it to update itself whenever one of the values in it changes.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: reasign your data provider to your grid.

Comment: Is there no better solution? Then my selectedIndex is no longer selected...

Comment: You can store the selected index in a variable, after the dataprovider changes, you can set it to that stored index.